# Visa requirements for going on a trip across Europe, from Netherlands to Croatia

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, croatia

I currently study in the UK on a Tier 4 Visa and require a Schengen Visa to visit the EU. I'll be visiting Netherlands, Germany, Austria, Slovenia, followed by Croatia, by taking trains. I'm staying in Germany for the longest period of time, so I will be applying to the German Embassy for a multiple entry Schengen Visa.

Under the German Embassy's document requirements, it mentions that a return flight must be booked from the Schengen Area. I will be returning back to UK from Croatia via flight from Zagreb.

**My question is, since Croatia is not officially in the Schengen Area, would it satisfy the document requirement (where I must have a return flight from the Schengen Area). Would I be refused a visa as a result?**

Comment: Where is that requirement articulated? It's not on the Schengen visa code.  The actual requirement is to show that you will leave, not necessarily that you will  go back to where you came from.

Comment: http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html Under proof of travel section 3, it says "Confirmed return travel tickets: mentioning applicant’s name and travel dates to & from the Schengen Area".

Comment: It doesn't say that your return flight must be from the Schengen area, it says that you must prove that you will leave the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since Croatia is not officially in the Schengen Area, would it satisfy the document requirement (where I must have a return flight from the Schengen Area)

You should buy a train ticket from Slovenia to Croatia online and attach a copy if you can. If you can't, explain that in a cover letter and outline your itinerary.

Anyway, there's no guarantee you'll get a double/multiple-entry visa. If you don't, you'll need a Croatian visa as well.

Comment: I did exactly as you said. Bought a bus ticket from Slovenia to Croatia and also wrote a covering letter explaining why I need a multi entry visa. I was issued a multi entry visa. Thank you for your help! :)